# AngularJs print JSON objects in table format (custom format - 4 objects per row )

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an api which fetch data from server using angular Js $http method. now i want to print the data in a table format( Im well aware of this and tried this before without any problem)

My Json (Static for now in angular)

```
    var app = angular.module('viewPhoto', ['ngTable']);
app.controller('viewControl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {
    var data = [{image: "avatar5.png", name: "orange1"},
                 {image: "avatar5.png", name: "orange2"},
                 {image: "dummy.png", name: "apple3"},
                 {image: "avatar5.png", name: "orange4"},
                 {image: "avatar5.png", name: "orange5"},
                 {image: "avatar5.png", name: "orange6"},
                 {image: "avatar5.png", name: "orange7"},
                 {image: "avatar5.png", name: "orange8"}
                 ];

    $scope.images = data;

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 20          // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
```

so when i use ng-repeat it gives me result in the following format.

```
orange1 
orange2
orange3
orange4
orange5
```

what im, trying to achieve is data should be in the following format.

```
orange1  orange2  orange3 orange4 (i need only 4 object per row)
orange5  orange6  ...     ...
```

What i tried is table structure but it printed row by row(one object per row),so i changed my approach to go with div's

```
<div ng-controller="viewControl">
                    <div  id="main_parent_row" ng-repeat="img in images">
                        <div id="pic1" style="width: 150px; color:#FFF; height: 150px;                  background-color: red; clear:both;display:inline-block; ">
                        </div>
                </div>
```

I tried to use an div as parent div and fixed its width to 800px and inside parent i made an child div with width as 100 px to hold data - orange1, i taught if there is no space for 5th div to print in single row it will move to next row thus i can achieve my output format, but **ng-repeat forces my div to print** in next line so the data is printed line by line.
Questions:

1) Print json objects(4 per row - if i got 10 objects from api then it should be printed in 3 rows)

2 ) I need to make pagination to hold only 20 objects in one page.

*3)Do i need to change JSON FORMAT to make this simple in angular ?*

if I'm in using wrong approach please correct me, is there is any simple way to do this.( I spend some quality time googling and tried some fiddles too) Please throw me some light!

**[Fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/SanthoshNelson/0mzxLcr8/)**

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` repeats the element it is on.  Move the repeat down one.

If you do not already have it make sure you have `float:left;` divs you want to wrap.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/aeg2rtcu/)**

```
<div ng-controller="viewControl" >
     <div  id="main_parent_row" style="max-width:800px;">
          <div ng-repeat="img in images"
                   style="float:left; width: 150px; color:#FFF; height: 150px;
                   background-color: red; clear:both;display:inline-block; ">
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**For pagination**

I would take a look at [Michael Bromley's pagination directive](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) it is very popular and allows asynchronous server side paging.

*Also you had `id="pic1"` nested in the ng-repeat.  IDs should represent a unique element on a view,and you would have more than one so I removed it.*

Comment: please look this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/SanthoshNelson/0mzxLcr8/ i tried your solution it doesnt work if i include ng-repeat

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/0mzxLcr8/9/ You had the float left on the wrong element.

Comment: thank you @malkus, coming back to my original questions, 1) is there is any other way to do this in angular(in build directives) 2) pagination ? can you throw me some clues ?

Comment: Added a reference to a good pagination directive.  And I don't think you need a to wrap this in a directive.  You are not doing any special `DOM` manipulation.